# How to update isLoading state from within URLSession.dataTask() completion handler in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a view (called `AddressInputView`) in Swift which should do the following:

1. Get an address from user input
2. When user hits submit, start ProgressView animation and send the address to backend
3. Once the call has returned, switch to a ResultView and show results

My problem is that once the user hits submit, then the view switches to the ResultView immediately without waiting for the API call to return. Therefore, the ProgressView animation is only visible for a split second.

This is my code:

**AddressInputView**

```
struct AddressInputView: View {
    @State var buttonSelected = false
    @State var radius = 10_000 // In meters
    @State var isLoading = false
    @State private var address: String = ""
    @State private var results: [Result] = []

    func onSubmit() {
        if !address.isEmpty {
            fetch()
        }
    }

    func fetch() {
        results.removeAll()
        isLoading = true

        let backendUrl = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "BACKEND_URL") as? String ?? ""

        let escapedAddress = address.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) ?? ""
        let params = "address=\(escapedAddress)&radius=\(radius)"
        let fullUrl = "\(backendUrl)/results?\(params)"

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: fullUrl)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, _, _ in
            if data != nil {
                do {
                    let serviceResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultsServiceResponse.self, from: data!)
                    self.results = serviceResponse.results
                } catch let jsonError as NSError {
                    print("JSON decode failed: ", String(describing: jsonError))
                }
            }
            isLoading = false
        })

        buttonSelected = true
        task.resume()
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            if isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                VStack {
                    TextField(
                        "",
                        text: $address,
                        prompt: Text("Search address").foregroundColor(.gray)
                    )
                    .onSubmit {
                        onSubmit()
                    }

                    Button(action: onSubmit) {
                        Text("Submit")
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(
                        isPresented: $buttonSelected,
                        destination: { ResultView(
                            address: $address,
                            results: $results
                        )
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, I tried to move `buttonSelected = true` right next to `isLoading = false` within the completion handler for `session.dataTask` but if I do that ResultView won't be shown. Could it be that state updates are not possible from within `completionHandler`? If yes, why is that so and what's the fix?

**Main Question:** How can I change the code above so that the ResultView won't be shown until the API call has finished? (While the API call has not finished yet, I want the ProgressView to be shown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the completion handler of `URLSession` is executed on a background thread. You have to dispatch the UI related API to the main thread.

But I recommend to take advantage of `async/await` and rather than building the URL with String Interpolation use `URLComponents/URLQueryItem`. It handles the necessary percent encoding on your behalf

```
func fetch() {
    results.removeAll()
    isLoading = true

    Task {
        let backendUrlString = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "BACKEND_URL") as! String
        var components = URLComponents(string: backendUrlString)!
        components.path = "/results"
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "address", value: address),
            URLQueryItem(name: "radius", value: "\(radius)")
        ]
    
        do {
            let (data, _ ) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: components.url!)
            let serviceResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultsServiceResponse.self, from: data)
            self.results = serviceResponse.results
            isLoading = false
            buttonSelected = true
        } catch {
            print(error)
            // show something to the user
        }
    }
}
```

The `URLRequest` is not needed, GET is the default.
And you can force unwrap the value of the Info.plist dictionary. If it doesn't exist you made a design mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Comparing with Ashley's solution, it seems like he added `async throws` to the function definition. Is this not required in your proposal?

Comment: No, it's only required if the asynchronous environment (the `Task`) is created by the caller of the function

Comment: I see, thanks. One follow-up question: I see that you replaced `request` with `components`. How do I pass custom http headers here? Up until now I used something like this but that's not possible any more because the request variable is gone: `request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [ "X-API-Key": apiKey ]`

Comment: No, I replaced the manual composition of the URL with `URLComponents`. Of course you need the `URLRequest` for additional parameters like headers. `var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)`

Comment: Thanks, if I use your code, I'm getting `Reference to captured var 'components' in concurrently-executing code` in this line: `let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: components.url!)`. You sure this works?

Comment: Move the line `Task {` up to the gap between `isLoading` and `let backendUrlString`. It would be still better to load the data in a  view model conforming to `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Ah yes, it's building the app now fine but when I run it, it jumps from showing the loading animation back to AddressInputView instead of going to ResultView. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Try `NavigationPath` as suggested by Ashley Mills.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fetch()` function calls an asynchronous function `session.dataTask` which returns immediately, before the data task is complete.

The easiest way to resolve this these days is to switch to using `async` functions, e.g.

```
func onSubmit() {
    if !address.isEmpty {
        Task {
            do {
                try await fetch()
            } catch {
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

func fetch() async throws {
    results.removeAll()
    isLoading = true

    let backendUrl = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "BACKEND_URL") as? String ?? ""

    let escapedAddress = address.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) ?? ""
    let params = "address=\(escapedAddress)&radius=\(radius)"
    let fullUrl = "\(backendUrl)/results?\(params)"

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: fullUrl)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let (data, _) = try await session.data(for: request)
    let serviceResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultsServiceResponse.self, from: data)
    self.results = serviceResponse.results
    isLoading = false
    buttonSelected = true
}
```

In the code above, the `fetch()` func is suspended while `session.data(for: request)` is called, and only resumes once it's complete.

From the `.navigationDestination` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vsplitview/navigationdestination(ispresented:destination:)):

> In general, favor binding a path to a navigation stack for programmatic navigation.

so add a `@State var path` to your view and use this `.navigationDestination` initialiser:

```
enum Destination {
    case result
}

@State private var path = NavigationPath()

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        if isLoading {
            ProgressView()
        } else {
            VStack {
                TextField("", text: $address, prompt: Text("Search address").foregroundColor(.gray))
                .onSubmit {
                    onSubmit()
                }
                Button(action: onSubmit) {
                    Text("Submit")
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self, destination: { destination in
                    switch destination {
                    case .result:
                        ResultView(address: $address, results: $results)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then at the end of your `fetch()` func, just set

```
isLoading = false
path.append(Destination.result)
```

---

*Example putting it all together*

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    
}

struct ResultsServiceResponse: Decodable {
    let results: [Result]
    
}

struct ResultView: View {
    @Binding var address: String
    @Binding var results: [Result]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(address)
    }
}

enum Destination {
    case result
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var radius = 10_000 // In meters
    @State var isLoading = false
    @State private var address: String = ""
    @State private var results: [Result] = []
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            if isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                VStack {
                    TextField("", text: $address, prompt: Text("Search address").foregroundColor(.gray))
                    .onSubmit {
                        onSubmit()
                    }
                    Button(action: onSubmit) {
                        Text("Submit")
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self, destination: { destination in
                        switch destination {
                        case .result:
                            ResultView(address: $address, results: $results)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onSubmit() {
        if !address.isEmpty {
            Task {
                do {
                    try await fetch()
                } catch {
                    print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetch() async throws {
        results.removeAll()
        isLoading = true
        
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000)
        self.results = [Result()]
        isLoading = false
        path.append(Destination.result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! If I use your code, then the loading animation is correctly shown while the api call is happening. However, when the call is done, the view will go abck to AddressInputView instead of ResultView. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Added more detail to my answer

Comment: Are you sure this works? Cause now I am getting `Cannot find 'Destination' in scope`

Comment: Sorry, I missed something when pasting the code. Updated

Comment: Hm, yes the build error is gone now but after the api call has finished and the loading animation is done, it still jumps back to AddressInputView instead of ResultView 

Comment: I've added the code I was working with. Note that this uses a simplified version of `fetch()`